# React leaflet map not correctly displayed even with leaflet.css import

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, ionic5, react-leaflet

I'm trying to create a map with reac-leaflet in ionic but I'm not displaying it correctly, also following this link: [Missing Leaflet Map Tiles when using react-leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55009403/missing-leaflet-map-tiles-when-using-react-leaflet)

WINDOW RESIZING FIX IT. What am I doing wrong on first login?

On first access this is the map:

[image]

After resizing:

[image]

Here the code.

In index.html

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>`

Home.tsx simplified.

```
import { Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet';

function Home() {

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar color="primary">
          <IonTitle>Logged in ... </IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent>
        <Map center={[45.24,8.55]} zoom={13}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={[45.24,8.55]}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
        </Map>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

In css file.

```
.leaflet-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to call `map.invalidateSize()` take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56184369/8283938

Comment: Your example works, even without using `invalidateSize`, but I'm using react-leaflet. In the example is used leaflet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with Ionic 5 and React Leaflet 3 and I solved like this:

In the page where you use the leaflet-react component (in your case ***Home***), import the useIonViewDidEnter lifecycle method ([see full docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/lifecycle)) to know when the IonPage has finished animating, then trigger a window-resize event.

```
import { IonPage, useIonViewDidEnter, ... } from '@ionic/react';
function Home() {

     /* 
      * trigger a 'window-resize' event when Page has finished, 
      * rendering and animating, so leaflet map can read a 
      * consistent height value
      */
     useIonViewDidEnter(() => {
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
     });

     return (
        <IonPage>
           ... your Leaflet component...
        </IonPage>
     );
}
```

Is working well for me.
Let me know if it helps.

Comment: This solves. I think it isn't the "right" way (react-leaflet must have something strange that happens at startup), but it is a good workaround. Thank you.

Comment: Here's well explained the reason why (under certain circumstances) it does not display correctly on the first render -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/36257493/5108194

I find the "window resize" method a good solution because it does not interfer with Leaflet instance, as invalidateSize() does.

But yes, is still a workaround :)

Comment: I added useIonViewDidEnter just before returning a MapContainer in a dedicated React component setting up the leaflet map and it fixed the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do currently and works for me:

**windowDimensions.tsx**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function getWindowDimensions() {
  const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
  return {
    width,
    height,
  };
}

export default function useWindowDimensions() {
  const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState(
    getWindowDimensions(),
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowDimensions;
}
```

**app.js or componentfile.js**

```
import useWindowDimensions from 'path/to/useWindowDimensions'; //in my case i saved it as app/utils/windowDimensions
    <Map style={{height: mapHeight}} />
```

Note: app.js only consist of code relevant to the fix

Comment: Same. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.3/leaflet.css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

Try this